# Query two spreadsheet tables and sum the results

Tags: google-sheets, tabular

I have a schedule table for each agent and another table for the type of users that each agent handles, i want to query and sum the results so that i can find out how many agents will handle each type of users everyday. Also i want to differentiate between 7AM,9AM and the evening shift.
Worth mentioning that both tables are of different sizes so i couldn't use Filter function.
[Sample of the two tables i'm querying and the result table i'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG1xZ.png)
How can i do this in spreadsheets?

I tried to use the filter function but didn't succeed because both tables are of different sizes also i don't know how to incorporate sumifs function with filter function plus i tried to use the importrange function since both tables are in different spreadsheets but failed

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Comment: I created [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VHTFtTFtVusgvmDvNlNXKkpX4E3VFEnPj_vXSC6GSkI/edit#gid=763715335) for you, i need to fill table (Groups Distribution Per day) in (Groups) tab.
For example, on 20/10/2023, only agents 11,33,34 are working the 9AM shift, agent 11 handles 4 groups and so do the rest of them, but only agent 11 handles (basic users) groups, so on 20/10/2023 we will have just 1 agent handling the basic users groups, same for (EGX Eligible) group, only agent 34 handles it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Added one possible solution to the test sheet for you check out:*

```js
=map(J2:J,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,bycol(K1:U1,lambda(Γ,sum(map(filter('[Consolidated] Rotational Shifts'!A6:A46,filter('[Consolidated] Rotational Shifts'!B6:I46,'[Consolidated] Rotational Shifts'!B5:I5=Σ)=I1),lambda(Λ,countif(filter(E:H,D:D=Λ),Γ)))))))))
```

[image]

1. `map(J2:J,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,` : *processing dates in `J2:J` one by one & ***Σ*** is identifier used for the date which can be used in later steps (you can change it as per your choice)*
2. `bycol(K1:U1,lambda(Γ,` : *processing group headers in `K1:U1` one by
   one*
3. `filter('[Consolidated] Rotational Shifts'!A6:A46,filter('[Consolidated] Rotational Shifts'!B6:I46,'[Consolidated] Rotational Shifts'!B5:I5=Σ)=I1)`:
   *filtering agent numbers in `consolidated` tab based on date from step* 1
4. `countif(filter(E:H,D:D=Λ),Γ)`: *filtering group names from
   columns_E_to_H based on agent numbers obtained in Step 3 and checks for the respective group header(from step 2) to take a count*
5. *the countif values obtained in step4 are all summed up and thrown as the output*

*[this basic tutorial](https://youtu.be/kUur-tMdTbo) should be helpful in understanding how map/lambda thing works and all...*

Comment: Thanks alot man, i'd really appreciate it if you walk me through the logic of your solution because i don't really understand it, also i'd be grateful if you can recommend a source that will help me master google spreadsheets through practical examples for advanced use cases like this one.

Comment: Added some basic explanation stuff on how the formula works...